# How can I fix the following error when using the zip() function? TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

I am using python 3.6.

I am attempting to take 2 python lists, and write them into a csv file. I need the first list to be in the first column, and the second list to be in the second column.

Many of the solutions I have found include using the zip() function as shown below, but I'm getting an error that I cannot seem to fix:

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

```
 zip_codes = ['code', '64148', '67118', '40813', '18229']
 rates = ['rate', 190.32, 99.53, 228.42, 190.32]

 col_format = "{:<5}"*2 + "\n"

 with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
      for sol in zip(zip_codes, rates): //ERROR OCCURS HERE
      f.write(col_format.format(*sol))
```

I'm expecting test.csv to contain 2 columns, whose values correspond to each list.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. btw what is `x`, as in `col_format.format(*x)` ?

Comment: It looks like you've set `zip = <somelist>`. Try `print(zip)` and if it doesn't say `<class 'zip'>`, that's your errror.

Comment: Sorry, that should be col_format.format(*sol), I've fixed it in the edit. But that's not the error I was confused about nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're getting the `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` error is likely because you have overridden `zip` as a variable by naming your list of zip codes as `zip`, which you apparently have corrected in the code you posted in the question but not in your actual code.

Moreover, your iteration variable for the `for` loop is named `sol`, which does not match the variable `x` you're unpacking for output.

With your variable names and indentation issues fixed, your code should look like:

```
zip_codes = ['code', '64148', '67118', '40813', '18229']
rates = ['rate', 190.32, 99.53, 228.42, 190.32]
col_format = "{:<6}" * 2 + "\n"
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    for cols in zip(zip_codes, rates):
        f.write(col_format.format(*cols))
```